# How to get data from SQL database to store in to a combo box - C#

Tags: c#, .net

How can i get the value of outlet ID  it on a comboBox? 
here is my code to getting the values from Database and store it on a combobox.

```
public partial class Addstock : Form
{
    String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TCConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    List<BOStockTransfer> StockList = new List<BOStockTransfer>();
    int updateIndex = -1;

    public Addstock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Addstock_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadstock();
        GetOutlets();
        Getproduct();
        GetGetWH();
        cmdoutletID.Visible = false;
        lbloutid.Visible = false;
        cmdwh.Visible = false;
        lblwh.Visible = false;
    }

    private void GetOutlets()
    {


        BOStockTransfer obj_StockTransfer = new BOStockTransfer();
        DataSet ds_OutletList = obj_StockTransfer.GetOutlets(connectionString);

        if (ds_OutletList.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            cmdoutletID.DataSource = ds_OutletList.Tables[0];
            cmdoutletID.DisplayMember = "outletId";
        }

    }
```

[image: My Database]
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What's the result? Are you getting errors?

Comment: i can't see  values of outlet ID in combo box

Comment: What do you want? What error do you have? Please be nore specific.

Comment: I want to fill a combobox from a column taken from my database

Comment: column name = outletId

Answer (score 0):

you are setting :

```
cmdoutletID.Visible = false;
```

what makes the combobox invisible

you have to set it as follows :

```
cmdoutletID.Visible = true;
```

After you added the images , the column name is `outletID` and Not `outletId`
so change your code as follows :

```
private void GetOutlets()
    {
    BOStockTransfer obj_StockTransfer = new BOStockTransfer();
    DataSet ds_OutletList = obj_StockTransfer.GetOutlets(connectionString);

    if (ds_OutletList.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        cmdoutletID.DataSource = ds_OutletList.Tables[0];
        cmdoutletID.DisplayMember = "outletID";
        cmdoutletID.ValueMember = "outletID";
        cmdoutletID.Enabled = true;

    }

}
```

Comment: @ChathuraKanchana I edited my answer , tell me if It works

Comment: @ChathuraKanchana I edited the answer again according to the image you sent , try the new code

Comment: still nothing happen

Comment: @ChathuraKanchana Have you tested if your query is returning any data ?

Answer (score 0):

The combo box has two properties which determine where it loads data from:

```
DisplayMember

ValueMember
```

The "ValueMember" property defines which named field populates the ListItem's "ValueProperty".  That way, when you do `combobox.SelectedItem.Value`, you will get the value stored in the named field you specified for "ValueProperty".

Assuming that you are certain that your query is returning rows, perhaps try adding the items "manually" rather than relying on automatic databinding.

```
private void GetOutlets()
{
    BOStockTransfer obj_StockTransfer = new BOStockTransfer();
    DataSet ds_OutletList = obj_StockTransfer.GetOutlets(connectionString);

    cmdoutletID.DisplayMember = "outletId";
    cmdoutletID.ValueMember = "pkID";
    cmdoutletID.BeginUpdate();
    try
    {
        cmdoutletID.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var row in ds_OutletList.Tables[0].Rows)
            cmdoutletID.Items(new { outletid = row["outletid"], pkID = row["primaryKeyIDFieldName"] });

    }
    finally { cmdoutletID.EndUpdate(); }
}
```

Comment: Error 3 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' could be found

Comment: Sorry, apparently I've been doing too much ASP.NET development.  You are correct that Windows.Forms controls do not implement an explicit `DataBind()` method.  I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BOStockTransfer obj_StockTransfer = new BOStockTransfer();
        DataSet ds_OutletList = obj_StockTransfer.GetOutlets(connectionString);

        if (ds_OutletList.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            cmdoutletID.DataSource = ds_OutletList.Tables[0];
            cmdoutletID.DisplayMember = "outletname";
            cmdoutletID.ValueMember = "outletId";
        }
```

To capture selected value, for example on button click:

```
protected button1_Click(object o, EventArgs e)
{
  var selectedId =  cmboutletID.SelectedValue;
MessageBox.Show(selectedId);
}
```